# in GraphQL, Can I send variables with Content-Type: application/graphql?

Tags: graphql

I've tried to use variables with graphql, 
but it seems impossible to send variables with 'application/graphql'.

Should i have to move on to Content-Type: 'application/json'?

Comment: can you please provide some more precise information about your approach to send variables? what does the http request look like? "it seems impossible to send variables with 'application/graphql'." --> what exactly do you mean by that? why does it seem impossible? are you getting an error? what does it say?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request

> A standard GraphQL POST request should use the application/json content type, and include a JSON-encoded body of the following form:

```
{
  "query": "...",
  "operationName": "...",
  "variables": { "myVariable": "someValue", ... }
}
```

> operationName and variables are optional fields. operationName is only required if multiple operations are present in the query.
>
> In addition to the above, we recommend supporting two additional cases:
>
> ...
>   If the "application/graphql" Content-Type header is present, treat the HTTP POST body contents as the GraphQL query string.

In my understanding, `Content-Type: "application/graphql"` is Shorthand for Querying without variables.

So my answer is "Yes, If I want to use variables field, I have to use `Content-Type: "application/json"` header

Answer (score 3):

What prevents you from passing the variables in the query string and the query in the body?

```
POST /graphql?variables={"id":1234}
Content-Type: application/graphql
query ($id: ID!) {
    Post(id: $id) {
        id
        title
        body
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, variables can works with the queryString? I didn't get it. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: POST requests do not usually have a query string. Doing some basic web searches, this is acceptable per the web standards, but is not conventional.

Answer (score 0):

According to Facebook's [express-graphql HTTP Usage](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql#http-usage), variables can be passed as URL parameters. Here is an example:

```
/graphql?query=query+getUser($id:ID){user(id:$id){name}}&variables={"id":"4"}
```

For `application/json`, there is separate section for variables. For POST body with `application/graphql` and GET requests, URL query: `variables={...}` can be used.