# "Problems parsing JSON" while sending a http request to a graphql api

Tags: json, node.js, http, github, graphql

I'm trying to send a http request to Githubs graphql api(v4). My guess is that the format of my query is wrong. The code below is used to send a POST request to the api.

```js
app.get('/fetch-data', function(req, res, next) {
    const access_token = settings.dev.TOKEN;
    const query = {query: { viewer: { 'login': 'muckbuck' } }};

    const options = {
        uri: 'https://api.github.com/graphql',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': "Bearer " + access_token,
            'User-Agent': 'request',
            'contentType': "application/graphql",
        },
        data: query
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        console.log(response.body)
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
            console.log('lol');
        }
    }
    request(options, callback);



});
```

The error message that I get:

```json
{"message":"Problems parsing JSON","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

Comment: Sure about "contentType"? Shouldn't that be "content-type"???

Comment: Yes I think you are right but sadly it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your GraphQL is malformed in that the `query` key is supposed to contain a string, not a complex structure. See also [this example](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#communicating-with-graphql) from the GitHub API documentation.

You may also want to set `Content-Type` to `application/json` as is recommended by the [GraphQL introduction](http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request). `application/graphql` does not seem to be a [registered media type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application) and appears to [alter the behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43732764/3012385) of GraphQL.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the query to: 
 { "query": "query:{viewer:{login}}" };. I also changed the Content-Type to application/json but it's still not parsing correctly :/. There was also a note about escaping some characters in the link, don't know how to do that, will have to google it I guess.

Comment: Try with `{ "query": "query { viewer { login } }" }`.  GraphQL isn't JSON. Again, check [the example](https://developer.github.com/v4/guides/forming-calls/#communicating-with-graphql).