# graphQL in python post request to get data

Tags: python, curl, post, request, graphql

Hi I was trying to figure out how to correctly pass a graphQL query to a python post request.

The sample graphQL is in curl like this on commission junction API website:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <your-personal-access-token> -XPOST 
https://commissions.api.cj.com/query -d '{ publisherCommissions(forPublishers: ["999"], sincePostingDate:"2018-08-08T00:00:00Z",beforePostingDate:"2018-08-09T00:00:00Z"){count payloadComplete records {actionTrackerName websiteName advertiserName postingDate pubCommissionAmountUsd items { quantity perItemSaleAmountPubCurrency totalCommissionPubCurrency }  }  } }'
```

I try to use python to simulate the request:

```
import requests
headers = {"Authorization": "Bear token"}

def run_query(query):
  request = requests.post('https://commissions.api.cj.com/query', json={'query': query}, headers=headers)
  if request.status_code == 200:
    return request.json()
  else:
    raise Exception("Query failed to run by returning code of {}. {}".format(request.status_code, query))

query="""
{
  publisherCommissions(forPublishers: ["999"]) {
    records
  }
}
"""

result = run_query(query)
```

But always get response 400. I don't know if python can take the graphQL format at all? how do i format so the post request can recognize it. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't `payload` be a string?

Comment: https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request documents the request format; it should be pretty straightforward to send it using `requests`.

Comment: it doesn't help me resolve the issue, I did change the format to 'query': query, still got 400

Comment: Maybe this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675933/in-graphql-can-i-send-variables-with-content-type-application-graphql , have you tried setting content type in the headers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked

```
   query = """
        {
          advertiserCommissions(forAdvertisers: "inputID",sinceEventDate: "%s",
            beforeEventDate: "%s")  {
          records {
            commissionId
            orderDiscountPubCurrency
            aid
            orderId
            postingDate
            lockingDate
            actionStatus
            advertiserId
            advertiserName
            saleAmountUsd
            originalActionId
            pubCommissionAmountUsd
            cjFeeUsd
            actionTrackerId
            actionType
            eventDate
            original
            actionTrackerName
        }
          limit
          maxCommissionId
          payloadComplete
          count
        }
        }
        """ % (beginDate, endDate)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this solution, it really helped me to pass dynamic values.